# Как элементы размещаются в map?

Tags: c++

```
void ZLab10::mapa()
 {
 map<char,double> pomiary;

 pomiary.insert(pair<char,double>('A',20));
 pomiary.insert(pair<char,double>('B',30));
 pomiary.insert(pair<char,double>('C',50));
 pomiary.insert(pair<char,double>('D',25));
 pomiary.insert(pair<char,double>('A',20));
 pomiary.insert(pair<char,double>('A',40));

 cout << "Pokaz mapy" << endl;
 for( char c : {'A','B','C'})
 cout << c << "->" << pomiary[c] << endl;

 cout << "Obczyslenia A -> " << pomiary.count('A') << endl;

 pomiary.erase('A');
 cout << "Pokaz mapy" << endl;
 for( char c : {'A','B','C'})
 cout << c << "->" << pomiary[c] << endl;
 cout << "Policz A -> " << pomiary.count('A') << endl;
 }
```

Как элементы в строках с 5 по 10 размещаются в map? Как осуществляется доступ к элементу map в строке 14?

Comment: map это самобалансирующееся (красно-черное) бинарное дерево поиска

Comment: Внутри какая-нибудь структура данных, обеспечивающая вставку, поиск и удаление элемента за логарифм от количества элементов. Обычно это [красно-чёрное дерево](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%91%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE). Стандарт не требует, чтобы это было именно оно. Он только накладывает ограничения на сложность операций с контейнером. Так что внутри может быть и, например, [АВЛ-дерево](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9B-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE) или ещё что-нибудь.